# Can I associate constant values with enums?

Tags: dart

I have an enum with each of its members having an associated guid, currently implemented with a getter inside an extension to this enum. I get a guid from an external service, and I want to match that up to my enum through this guid getter. These guid values don't change; is there a way I can make them compile-time constants, so they work with switch statements?

Edit: I was asked for an example, here is a little code that illustrates what I'm asking about (edited after feedback):

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

enum Service {
  aiding('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d1'),
  ota('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17');

  const Service(this.label);
  
  final String label;
  
  bool get isAiding => Service.aiding == this;
  bool get isOta => Service.ota == this;
  String get guid => label;
}

void main() {
  switch('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17') {
    case Service.aiding.guid:
      print("aiding");
      break;
    case Service.ota.guid:
      print("ota");
      break;
    default:
      print("guid not found");
  }
}
```

When trying to Run this on DartPad I get multiple errors, starting with:

```
Error compiling to JavaScript:
Info: Compiling with sound null safety
lib/main.dart:21:18:
Error: Not a constant expression.
    case Service.aiding.guid:
                 ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Can you provide a small sample so we can see what you want?

Comment: Would it work for you to do `switch (service.guid.toString()) { case "00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17": .... }`?

Comment: @Irn that code would work, but it loses the gains from using enums; it's not very readable and it would be easy to make mistakes.

Comment: It seems to me that you wouldn't need to switch on the `Guid` for each `enum` case; instead you could switch on the case itself: `switch(service) { case Service.aiding: _setAidingCharacteristics(service);` etc

Comment: Your switch method is bad. You should put the service `enum` `label` to `switch` constructor and `String` ids to cases. Service `label` is `String` and your `guid` is `String`, so no matter what you put to switch `method` constructor`.

Comment: @Arnas I wanted to reference the guids in the case statements through the enum so they would be readable and I wouldn't have to repeat these strings. I was hoping to use this through enums, but I'll assign my strings to consts instead so I can name them, and then return those from the enum; verbose, but clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for functional enums. Here are some examples:

```dart
enum Service { aiding, ota }

extension ServiceExtension on Service {
  // You can create any function to match your preferences.
  R guidWhen<R>({
    required R Function(Guid guid) aiding,
    required R Function(Guid guid) ota,
  }) {
    switch (this) {
      case Service.aiding:
        return aiding(Guid('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d1'));
      case Service.ota:
        return ota(Guid('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17'));
    }
  }

  R when<R>({
    required R Function() aiding,
    required R Function() ota,
  }) {
    switch (this) {
      case Service.aiding:
        return aiding();
      case Service.ota:
        return ota();
    }
  }

  R maybeWhen<R>({
    R Function()? aiding,
    R Function()? ota,
    required R Function() orElse,
  }) {
    if (aiding != null && Service.aiding == this) {
      return aiding();
    } else if (ota != null && Service.ota == this) {
      return ota();
    } else {
      return orElse();
    }
  }

  R map<R>({
    required R Function(Service service) aiding,
    required R Function(Service service) ota,
  }) {
    switch (this) {
      case Service.aiding:
        return aiding(this);
      case Service.ota:
        return ota(this);
    }
  }

  R maybeMap<R>({
    R Function(Service service)? aiding,
    R Function(Service service)? ota,
    required R Function() orElse,
  }) {
    if (aiding != null && Service.aiding == this) {
      return aiding(this);
    } else if (ota != null && Service.ota == this) {
      return ota(this);
    } else {
      return orElse();
    }
  }

  // You can add more functions based on your preferences...
}

// Test element.
class Guid {
  Guid(this.id);

  String id;

  @override
  String toString() => 'Guid(id: $id)';

  @override
  bool operator ==(covariant Guid guid) => guid.id == id;

  @override
  int get hashCode => id.hashCode;
}
```

Usage:

```dart
void main() {
  final service = Service.ota;

  service.guidWhen(aiding: print, ota: print);
  // Output: Guid(id: 00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17);
  
  // Or even you can make like that:
  service.guidWhen(aiding: _setAidingCharacteristics, ota: _setAidingCharacteristics);
}
```

#### Update:

Dart 2.17 will support more useful `enum` data classes.

```dart
enum Service {
  aiding('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d1'),
  ota('00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d17');

  const Service(this.label);
  
  final String label;
  
  bool get isAiding => Service.aiding == this;
  bool get isOta => Service.ota == this;
  Guid get guid => Guid(label);
}

void main() {
  final service = Service.aiding;
  print(service.isOta); // false
  print(service.isAiding); // true
  print(service.guid); // Guid(id: 00000001-34ed-12ef-63f4-317792041d1)
}
```

Comment: Will the new enum data classes let me use these guids in the cases of switches?

Comment: Yes.  You can play with new `enum` data classes in DartPad on the beta channel. As you see in my example `guid` getter work as switch cases.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it on the DartPad beta channel, and I updated my question with my results.

Comment: I think you don't need switch method. Functional enums do same and in cleaner way.